# Making a table excluding a region; conditional iteration

Tags: plotting, regions

I just would like to create the table with the following condition; selecting the points outside a circle

```
Norm[{x, y}] > 0.5
```

I used

```
dataee = 
  Flatten[
    Table[
      {x, y, Phi[x, y] && Norm[{x, y}] > 0.51}, 
      {x, 0.01, 1.3, 0.05}, {y, 0.01, 1.3, 0.05}],
    1];
```

but `ListContourPlot` still shows the contours inside that circle (the excluded region) which makes the plot useless.

What is the proper way to include this condition while iterating over the loops?

In case one needs the function:

```
zc = -1.8;
zp = 0.9;
qe = 1.0;
a = 0.22;
σ = 0.5;
κ = 5.0/σ;
ϵ = 80.0;

Phi[x_, y_] := 
  (qe^2/ϵ) (Exp[-κ Norm[{x, y}]]/Norm[{x, y}]) (Exp[κ σ]/((1 + κ σ)))^2 
    ((zc^2 + 2 zc zp 
      (Sum[(a/σ)^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, Cos[ArcTan[y, x]]] Boole[i/2 ∈ Integers], {i, 1, 200}])) + 
     (zc zp + 
        2 zp^2 (Sum[(a/σ)^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, Cos[ArcTan[y + a, x]]] Boole[i/2 ∈ Integers], {i, 1, 200}])) 
     (Exp[-κ Norm[{x, y}] ((Norm[{x, y + a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) - 1] / 
        (Norm[{x, y + a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) + 
     (zc zp + 
        2 zp^2 
          (Sum[(a/σ)^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, Cos[ArcTan[y - a, x]]] Boole[i/2 ∈ Integers], {i, 1, 200}])) 
     (Exp[-κ Norm[{x, y}] ((Norm[{x, y - a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) - 1] / 
       (Norm[{x, y - a}]/Norm[{x, y}])));
```

[image: This is the plot]
This is the plot

**Edit:**

I can do something similar to the below lines which excludes the points inside the above mentioned circle, but I cannot plot the data. I do not know what is the problem, Flatten does not work and the ListContourPlot output is a blank plot. Here is the method; same function and parameters, instead the output is written into a file.

```
For[x = 0.01 , x <= 1.3, x += 0.1,
 For[y = 0.01 , y <= 1.3, y += 0.1,
If[Norm[{x, y}] > 0.5, { x, y, Phi[x, y]} >>> "EE.dat"];  ]]
```

Comment: It might have to do with interpolation. Notice that your data will contain points `{x, y, False}` which I would remove before plotting. Try `ListContourPlot[DeleteCases[dataee, {_, _, False}], 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Epilog -> {Red, Thin, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.5]}]` as a start.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what Thank you, I think my main problem is in the construction of the table. Using your command, still it shows the points inside the circle. I will look at it carefully.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Clear["`*"];
    zc = -1.8;
    zp = 0.9;
    qe = 1.0;
    a = 0.22;
    σ = 0.5;
    κ = 5.0/σ;
    ϵ = 80.0;
    
    Phi[x_?NumericQ, 
      y_?NumericQ] := (qe^2/ϵ) (Exp[-κ Norm[{x, y}]]/
        Norm[{x, 
          y}]) (Exp[κ σ]/((1 + κ σ)))^2 \
    ((zc^2 + 2 zc zp (Total@
             Table[(a/σ)^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, 
                Cos[ArcTan[y, x]]], {i, 2, 200, 2}])) + (zc zp + 
           2 zp^2 (Total@
              Table[(a/σ)^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, 
                 Cos[ArcTan[y + a, x]]], {i, 2, 200, 
                2}])) (Exp[-κ Norm[{x, 
                y}] ((Norm[{x, y + a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) - 
             1]/(Norm[{x, y + a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) + (zc zp + 
           2 zp^2 (Total@
              Table[(a/σ)^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, 
                 Cos[ArcTan[y - a, x]]], {i, 2, 200, 
                2}])) (Exp[-κ Norm[{x, 
                y}] ((Norm[{x, y - a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) - 
             1]/(Norm[{x, y - a}]/Norm[{x, y}])));
 data = 
     Table[{x, y, Phi[x, y]}, {x, 0.01, 1.3, 0.02}, {y, 0.01, 1.3, 0.02}];
    newdata = 
      Cases[{a_Real, b_Real, c_Real} /; Norm[{a, b}] > 0.5] /@ data;
    ListContourPlot[Flatten[newdata, 1], 
     RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#1, #2}] > 0.55 &), Contours -> 20, 
     ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

```
Clear["`*"];
zc = -1.8;
zp = 0.9;
qe = 1.0;
a = 0.22;
\[Sigma] = 0.5;
\[Kappa] = 5.0/\[Sigma];
\[Epsilon] = 80.0;
Phi[x_?NumericQ, 
   y_?NumericQ] := (qe^2/\[Epsilon]) (Exp[-\[Kappa] Norm[{x, y}]]/
     Norm[{x, 
       y}]) (Exp[\[Kappa] \[Sigma]]/((1 + \[Kappa] \[Sigma])))^2 \
((zc^2 + 2 zc zp (Total@
          Table[(a/\[Sigma])^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, 
             Cos[ArcTan[y, x]]], {i, 2, 200, 2}])) + (zc zp + 
        2 zp^2 (Total@
           Table[(a/\[Sigma])^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, 
              Cos[ArcTan[y + a, x]]], {i, 2, 200, 
             2}])) (Exp[-\[Kappa] Norm[{x, 
             y}] ((Norm[{x, y + a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) - 
          1]/(Norm[{x, y + a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) + (zc zp + 
        2 zp^2 (Total@
           Table[(a/\[Sigma])^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, 
              Cos[ArcTan[y - a, x]]], {i, 2, 200, 
             2}])) (Exp[-\[Kappa] Norm[{x, 
             y}] ((Norm[{x, y - a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) - 
          1]/(Norm[{x, y - a}]/Norm[{x, y}])));
data = Table[{x, y, Phi[x, y]}, {x, 0.01, 1.3, 0.02}, {y, 0.01, 1.3, 
    0.02}];
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[data, 1], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Norm[{x, y}] > 0.51]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, I simplified function `Phi` to speed-up computation:

```
zc = -1.8;
zp = 0.9;
qe = 1.0;
a = 0.22;
\[Sigma] = 0.5;
\[Kappa] = 5.0/\[Sigma];
\[Epsilon] = 80.0;

Phi[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := (qe^2/\[Epsilon]) (Exp[-\[Kappa] Norm[{x, y}]]/
 Norm[{x, y}]) (Exp[\[Kappa] \[Sigma]]/((1 + \[Kappa] \[Sigma])))^2 \
((zc^2 + 2 zc zp (Total@
      Table[(a/\[Sigma])^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, 
         Cos[ArcTan[y, x]]], {i, 2, 200, 2}])) + (zc zp + 
    2 zp^2 (Total@
       Table[(a/\[Sigma])^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, 
          Cos[ArcTan[y + a, x]]], {i, 2, 200, 2}])) (Exp[-\[Kappa] Norm[{x, 
         y}] ((Norm[{x, y + a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) - 
      1]/(Norm[{x, y + a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) + (zc zp + 
    2 zp^2 (Total@
       Table[(a/\[Sigma])^i (2 i + 1) LegendreP[i, 
          Cos[ArcTan[y - a, x]]], {i, 2, 200, 2}])) (Exp[-\[Kappa] Norm[{x, 
         y}] ((Norm[{x, y - a}]/Norm[{x, y}])) - 
      1]/(Norm[{x, y - a}]/Norm[{x, y}])));
```

Now we can plot:

```
ListContourPlot[Table[Phi[x, y], {x, 0.01, 1.3, 0.05}, {y, 0.01, 1.3, 0.05}], 
RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#1, #2}] > 0.51 &), 
DataRange -> {{0.01, 1.3}, {0.01, 1.3}}, Contours -> 20,
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think still the problem is there, the white areas around the circle are actually artifacts due to the fact that we are calculating the potential inside the circle which makes the contour plot inaccurate. I need to remove all the points inside the circle (<0.5) before plotting to make the contour plot more accurate.